# Why ViewState and Control Values lost on partial Postback using AJAXFileUpload?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, popup, state-management

I have a `.aspx` page containing button which opens the `popup` on button click. 
The popup window have `AJAXFileUpload` control. When button is clicked to open the popup, `session` values are sent to popup and on `page load` these `session` values are assigned to `ViewState` and `HiddenField`, `DataTable`.

**Problem:**
When i `click` on `Upload` button in popup containing `AjaxFileUpload`it saves the images to the table in `AJAXUploadComplete` `event`. **In this event i am not able to access the `ViewState,HiddenField and DataTable`** Values dont know why?

**Popup.aspx.cs**

```
    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                int noOfImages;
                string[] imagePaths;
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count==0)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("QuoteID");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PrepID");
                    dt.Columns.Add("IsPrep");
                    dt.Rows.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
                }
                if ((!IsPostBack ))
                {
                    if (Session["IsPrep"] != null || ViewState["IsPrep"]!= null)
                    {
                       int Isprep = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IsPrep"].ToString());

                       if (Session["IsPrep"] != null)
                       {
                           ViewState["IsPrep"] = Session["IsPrep"];
                           ViewState["QuoteID"] = Convert.ToString(Session["QuoteIDForListing"]);
 int intQuoteID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QuoteID"]);
                        hdnQuoteID.Value = intQuoteID.ToString();
                           ViewState["PrepID"] = Convert.ToString(Session["PrepIDForListing"]);

                           if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                           {
                               dt.Rows[0]["QuoteID"] = Convert.ToString(Session["QuoteIDForListing"]);
                               dt.Rows[0]["PrepID"] = Convert.ToString(Session["PrepIDForListing"]);
                               dt.Rows[0]["IsPrep"] = Convert.ToString(Session["IsPrep"]);
                           }

                           Session["IsPrep"] = null;
                           Session["QuoteIDForListing"] = null;
                           Session["PrepIDForListing"] = null;

                       }
                    }
                 }
       }

 protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete1(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
         //here: ViewState,HiddenField,DataTable values are all get cleared dont know why?
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            { 
                //here dt is set to null any idea?
            }
           //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ViewState["QuoteID"])))
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(hdnQuoteID.Value))&& hdnIsPrepId.Value=="0")
                {
                    int QuoteID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QuoteID"]);
                    ///some code here
                }
               // else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ViewState["PrepID"])))
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(hdnPrepID.Value)) && hdnIsPrepId.Value == "1")
                {
                    int PrepID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PrepID"]);
                   ///some code here
                }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Same functionality works fine on a page. But, used with the popup it flushed all the values of `HiddenField,DataTable,ViewState.` 
   `Session` cant be used to store data after popup opened because multiple instance of windows may be opened at a time.

Also, when `query string`  is used with Popup to send values the `AjaxFileUpload` gives error as it appends `its own querystring` contextkey and guid.

Please suggest any solution/change?